# Смысл слова "составлять" у Писарева

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Труд составляет самую крепкую и надежную связь между тем человеком, который трудится, и тем обществом, на пользу которого направлен этот труд.*

Эти слова, написанные Писаревым в 1865 году (Д. И. ПИСАРЕВ «Школа и жизнь»), используются в заданиях для школьников.

Мне кажется, ни одно из современных значений слова "составлять" не подходит для этой фразы. Прав ли я? Предполагаю, что Писарев имел в виду "создает". Существовало ли такое значение слова "составлять" во времена Писарева?

Более широкий контекст:

*Мыслящий человек, выбравший себе какую-нибудь отрасль труда и пристрастившийся к своей деятельности, любит свою родину особенно сильно потому, что чувствует себя полезным для нее и лишним во всякой другой стране. Труд составляет самую крепкую и надежную связь между тем человеком, который трудится, и тем обществом, на пользу которого направлен этот труд. Поэтому, развивая в своих воспитанниках рабочие силы и любовь к труду, школа готовит из них превосходных патриотов, хотя бы даже эти патриоты не имели никакого понятия о том, кто такой был Рюрик и что такое он сделал 1003 года тому назад.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы правы, здесь имеется в виду значение "создавать".

В словаре Ушакова такое значение фиксируется, есть и у Ожегова, Шведовой

8. Образовать, **создать,** явиться чем-н. «Этот **брак может составить ваше счастье.**» Тургенев. «Ты обязан составить счастие женщины, которую ты любишь.»

См.: Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949-1992.

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.

Answer (score 0):

В современном языке  слово "составляет"  может иметь  значение "является".

В словаре Кузнецова (Публикуется в авторской редакции 2014 года):
**СОСТАВИТЬ**,  св. что.  4. **Явиться чем-л., представить собой что-л**. С. чьё-л. счастье. Не составит большого труда что-л. сделать. Это не составит исключения.

Труд составляет (= является) самую крепкую и надежную связь....